# Elsarticle-harv : How to order bibliography in alphabetical order?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle

I am using an article with `[authoryear]` referencing throughout the text. However, when I compile the bibliography using `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}` , the references are not given in alphabetical order, and the authors are listed as: 'Joe Bloggs', rather than 'Bloggs, J.'

Is there a simple way to change this to the alphabetical style and in the form: 'Bloggs, J (2010)....'?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of only two things that may have happened to your document:

- you are not using the genuine [`elsarticle-harv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst) bibliography style; or
- after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle` to `elsarticle-harv`, you did not re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes stemming from the change in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`.

For sure, the genuine `elsarticle-harv` bibliographystyle (a) abbreviates the first and middle names of authors and places the initials *after* the surname and (b) sorts the entries alphabetically.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{bloggs:2010,
   author  = "Joe Bloggs",
   title   = "Thoughts",
   year    = 2010,
}
@misc{author:2016,
   author  = "Annie Aardvark and Zebulon Zwicky",
   title   = "Deep Thoughts",
   year    = 2016,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\begin{document}
\citet{bloggs:2010}, \citet{author:2016}
\section*{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```